# List all images in Mesosphere/Marathon

Tags: docker, marathon, mesosphere

I am using Mesosphere Marathon. ON Mesos we host our container application. The number of applications are more.
Is there a way we can list down all the container images which are being used in my Mesos rather than going one by one to check in each application configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script using the marathon API. See https://your.marathon.fqdn/api-console/index.html

The /v2/apps/ endpoint gives a json list of all applications. if you pipe this to jq (or maybe another tool) you can get the list of images:

```
curl https://your.marathon.fqdn/v2/apps | jq -r .apps[].container.docker.image
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with somewhat tedious way:
Pulled the apps information using http://fqdn:8080/v2/apps
Then using awk command segregated all the image names ex: awk '/image/ {print}'  listapp.json.....where listapp.json is the output from the above command